# Are two modules whose localizations are all isomorphic necessarily isomorphic?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $M$ and $N$ two $A$-modules.

It is well-known (see e.g. Proposition 3.9 in Atiyah and Macdonald) that if we have an $A$-linear map $\phi: M \to N$ such that for every $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, the localized map $\phi_\mathfrak{p}: M_\mathfrak{p} \to N_\mathfrak{p}$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi: M \to N$ is itself an isomorphism.

Suppose that we only know that for every $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, the localizations $M_\mathfrak{p}$ and $N_\mathfrak{p}$ are isomorphic. Can we deduce that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic?

Comment: No. Think of a projective module which is not free.

Comment: OK, for example take $M = k \times 0$ over $A = k \times k$. Then $A$ has two prime ideals, namely $k \times 0$ and $0 \times k$. We then have $M_{k \times 0} = 0$ and $M_{0 \times k} = A_{0 \times k} \simeq k$. But I do not see any other module $M'$ that would have the same localizations.

Comment: I think Mohan is suggesting an example like this: take a Dedekind domain $R$ that is not a PID and $I$ a nonprincipal ideal. Then $I_p \cong R_p$ for every prime ideal $p$ but $I$ is not isomorphic to $R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elaboration (or at least my interpretation) of Mohan's comment: if $M$ and $N$ are projective rank 1 (say) $A$-modules, then the localizations of both $M$ and $N$ at $p$ are isomorphic to $A_p$. Hence it suffices to find a ring $A$ with nontrivial Picard group.