# Local properties concerning finitely generated modules over a noetherian ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a commutative unital noetherian ring R and p a prime ideal of R, if M,N are finitely generated R-modules and Mp,Np are isomorphic, then Mf≃Nf for some f∈A−p. How to prove this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1972740/453628

Comment: Can someone give a concrete example to show that $M$ and $N$ are not isomorphic but $M_p\cong N_p$ for ecery prime ideal $p$?

Comment: @Sky $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, $M=R$, $N=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$. But you should explain why this relates to the problem.

Comment: @Sky I don't understand what the linked question has to do with this one, unless you wanted to ask another question and get an answer here instead of doing this in the appropriate place, that is, în the linked thread.

Comment: @user26857 I just want to say if there is a morphism $M\rightarrow N$ ,then induced $M_f\rightarrow N_f$,if for any prime ideal such that $f\notin p$,the induced morphism $M_p\rightarrow N_p$ is isomorphism,then $M_f\rightarrow N_f$ is isomorphism since $(M_f)_{p_f}\cong M_p$.